# Automate an Ant Script to run at set times

Tags: ant, cmd, cron, job-scheduling, windows-task-scheduler

I have a set up a build process to that requires an ant script to run. So I am  trying to automate this to run every day at a set time but I an not sure if this is possible from Windows Scheduler.

The cmd that I currently type in to from cmd is

```
ant -f ./Setup.xml LoadAllSoucres
```

Any advice would be very welcome.

Michael

Comment: Install Jenkins, see: https://jenkins-ci.org/

Comment: I am not able to install Jenkins on my PC as I do not have admin access.

Comment: Running Jenkins is not hard. Ideally it should be run as a service, but can just as easily be run as follows: "java -jar jenkins.war". I highly recommend reading the documentation. Finally if you can't install software on your PC consider a dedicate server that runs Jenkins and acts as a CI server triggered by code pushes to your source code repository.